# P5.js instance mode not working with matrix letter rain

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I´m a pretty beginner here and with classes in P5.js, :(

Trying to figure out to combine the P5.js instance mode with this fabulous tutorial: [Matrix Digital Rain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S1TQCi9axzg) in p5.js with Emily Xie.

When running the code, I have an uncaught ReferenceError ( "generateSymbols is not defined" ) in line 59, but this.generateSymbols is already defined in line 155...

Whats happening here?

```js
/* Poem Matrix
I am gonna risk, I am gonna risk the value of every single chance. Decent needs on time, part silence, part judgment.

I am gonna face, I am gonna face about ten people in a white hall praying for maintain the differences in a short conversation.

He stands up and draws a few steps across the living room. Then, he looks forward and she’s gone again. He stands up and draws a few steps across the living room. Then, he looks forward and she’s gone again.
*/

var letterRain = function (l) {
  var myFont;

  preload = function () {
    myFont = l.loadFont("fonts/CutiveMono-Regular.ttf");
    console.log("loaded");
  };

  var canvas;
  var streams = [];
  var symbolSize = 30;

  windowResized = function () {
    l.resizeCanvas(l.windowWidth, l.windowHeight);
    console.log("window resized");
  };

  l.setup = function () {
    canvas = l.createCanvas(l.windowWidth, l.windowHeight);
    canvas.position(0, 0);
    canvas.style("z-index", "-1");
    //background(255);
    var x = 0;
    console.log("canvas creado y posicionado");

    for (var i = 0; i < l.width / symbolSize; i++) {
      stream = new Stream();
      generateSymbols(x, l.random(-2000, 0));
      streams.push(stream);
      x += symbolSize;
    }

    textSize(symbolSize);
    textFont(myFont);
    console.log("he pasado por el for");
  };

  l.draw = function () {
    l.background(255);

    streams.forEach(function (stream) {
      stream.render();
    });

    console.log("he pasado por el draw");
  };

  /* Symbol Class*/

  function Symbol(x, y, speed) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.value;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.switchInterval = l.round(l.random(90, 200)); //el anterior era: 50, 100

    this.setToRandomSymbol = function () {
      if (frameCount % this.switchInterval == 0) {
        var lyric = [
          "I am",
          "gonna",
          "risk",
          "the",
          "value",
          "of",
          "every",
          "single chance",
          "Decent",
          "needs",
          "on",
          "time",
          "part",
          "silence",
          "part judgment",
          "she’s gone again",
          "short conversation",
          "looks forward",
          "draws",
          "conversation",
        ];

        this.value = lyric[l.floor(l.random(lyric.length))];
      }
      //console.log("he pasado");
    };

    this.rain = function () {
      this.y = this.y >= height ? 0 : (this.y += this.speed);
    };
    console.log("rain");
  }

  /* Stream Classs*/

  function Stream() {
    this.symbols = [];
    this.totalSymbols = l.round(l.noise(2, 8)); //la anterior era random en vez de noise
    this.speed = l.random(1, 2); //controla la velocidad el anterior: 1 5 y random en veez de noise

    this.generateSymbols = function (x, y) {
      for (var i = 0; i <= this.totalSymbols; i++) {
        symbol = new Symbol(x, y, this.speed);
        symbol.setToRandomSymbol();
        this.symbols.push(symbol);
        y -= symbolSize;
      }
      console.log("final");
    };

    this.render = function () {
      this.symbols.forEach(function (symbol) {
        l.fill(0, 0, 0);
        text(symbol.value, symbol.x, symbol.y);
        symbol.rain();
        symbol.setToRandomSymbol();
      });
    };
  }
}; //final de la funcion l

new p5(letterRain);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.5.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Should that be `this.generateSymbols` instead? Please try to get a simpler example working and post a [mcve] if you're still stuck. Good luck.

Comment: @KevinWorkman No, `this` only has scope inside its function.

Comment: @KevinWorkman thank you very much!, I finnaly went the right path, so everything is pretty working... Just pretty working, becuase when I´m trying the same code with brunch io, nothing happens :((

Answer (score 0):

Your code did not run on my machine, but I think i know why it doesn't work.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < l.width / symbolSize; i++) {

    stream = new Stream();

    stream.generateSymbols(x, l.random(-2000, 0));

    streams.push(stream);

    x += symbolSize

};
```

I think you have to add `stearm.generateSybols(...`

I hope this helped

Comment: Yeah!!! you got it!That was the problem... Ok, I ´ve done a few mistakes more (not properly definied global P5.js commands with the instace mode) but you put me in the right way. Thank you very much!, I´m gonna try to write here the whole correct code.

Comment: glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

`generateSymbols()` is being called as a global function but it hasn't been defined globally, hence why you are getting the error.

`generateSymbols()` is a function of `Stream` so it must be accessed from an instance of `Stream`. You already created this instance on the previous lines so all you need to do it add the steam instance variable.

```
stream.generateSymbols();
```